# How to programmatically hide navigationBar outside of viewDidLoad() using a function

Tags: ios, swift

I'm attempting to modify elements and pop/push views of a swift iOS app by running a function based on the response of messages received from a webview using ScriptMessageHandler.  How can I accomplish this? Things are wired up correctly and the function is being called, however it doesn't work.

For example, I've created a function hideIt() that hides the navigation bar.  If I run the function below triggered by a click on the hideShowButton which is a native button that I programmatically added to the view, it works.  However if I call the function directly from elsewhere, it does not.  All navigationController values are nil.

```
import Turbo
import UIKit

class VisitableViewController: Turbo.VisitableViewController {
        
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .background
        
    // Add button to view
    let hideShowButton: UIButton = {
      let button = UIButton()
      button.setTitle("Hide Nav", for: .normal)
      button.titleLabel?.tintColor = .white
      button.titleLabel?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 10)
      button.backgroundColor = .background_blue_900
      button.contentEdgeInsets = .init(top: 7, left: 10, bottom: 7, right: 10)
      button.layer.cornerRadius = 14
      button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.hideIt), for: .touchUpInside)
      return button
    }()
                 hideShowButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.view.addSubview(hideShowButton)
        hideShowButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        hideShowButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        
 }
    
    
    //start test
    
@objc func hideIt() {
  print("***start")
     visitableViewController.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
        
   print("navigationController:")
   print(navigationController)
        
   print("self.navigationController:")
   print(self.navigationController)
        
   print("navigationController?.visibleViewController")
   print(navigationController?.visibleViewController)
                 
print("navigationController?.visibleViewController?.navigationItem.title:")
        print(navigationController?.visibleViewController?.navigationItem.title)

    print("**end")
  }
}
```

The hideIt() function is called successfully when receiving the message goBack via Javascript.

```
import WebKit

protocol ScriptMessageDelegate: AnyObject {
    func signOut()
    func goBack()
}


class ScriptMessageHandler: NSObject, WKScriptMessageHandler {
    private weak var delegate: ScriptMessageDelegate?

    init(delegate: ScriptMessageDelegate) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }

    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        guard
            let body = message.body as? [String: Any],
            let message = ScriptMessage(body: body)
        else { return }
        print(message)
        routeMessage(message)
    }

    private func routeMessage(_ message: ScriptMessage) {
        switch message {
        case .signOut:
            delegate?.signOut()
        case .goBack:
            print("*********Run hideIt() in VisitableViewController when receiving goBack Javascript message")

            let visitable = VisitableViewController();
            visitable.hideIt()
        }
    }
    
}
```

As seen in the debug console.  When hideIt() is run all values are nil.

```
***start

VisitableViewController(): 
<Myapp.VisitableViewController: 0x103240c10>
navigationController:
nil
self.navigationController:
nil
navigationController?.visibleViewController
nil
navigationController?.visibleViewController?.navigationItem.title:
nil
**end
```

However, if I press the native button that calls the exactly same function, the values are correct and the navigation bar hides as expected.

```
***start
VisitableViewController(): 
<Myapp.VisitableViewController: 0x10335f4b0>
navigationController:
Optional(<UINavigationController: 0x104027000>)
self.navigationController:
Optional(<UINavigationController: 0x104027000>)
navigationController?.visibleViewController
Optional(<Jumpstart.VisitableViewController: 0x1032442e0>)
navigationController?.visibleViewController?.navigationItem.title:
Optional("My App Name")
**end
```

Comment: "Things are wired up correctly and the function is being called, however it doesn't work" No, they are not wired up correctly. You are probably talking to `VisitableViewController()` — which is not the right view controller.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance.  Can you explain a little more about VisitableViewController() not being the right view controller?  My updates show what is showing in the console under the two circumstances.

Comment: You are creating a new instance of your view controller and calling the function on it. This is not the view controller instance that is on screen so it has not effect.  You need the instance that is on screen, in the navigation hierarchy. You need to provide this instance somehow to your script delegate object

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake/

Comment: Thank you all, I'm reading into this.